# Postgres SELECT GROUP BY most selling item by publisher

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by

I have 3 tables:

```
publisher (id serial pkey, pub_name text)
book (id serial pkey, id_pub INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES publisher (id), book_name TEXT)
rank (id SERIAL PKEY, id_book INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES book (id), week DATE, selling INTEGER)
```

And want to list only the top selling book for each publisher. What I have by now returns the selling of all books:

```
SELECT publisher.pub_name, book.book_name, SUM(rank.selling)
 FROM rank, publisher, book
 WHERE rank.id_book = book.id AND book.id_pub = publisher.id
 GROUP BY publisher.pub_name, book.book_name;
```

Returns like that:

```
BigPublisher, Book1, 100300
GoodPublisher, BeBook, 10003
BigPublisher, Book2, 50200
OldPublisher, N-Book, 20009
GoodPublisher, CeBook, 4000
GoodPublisher, DeBook, 3001
```

Where I'm looking for that kind of result:

```
BigPublisher, Book1, 100300
GoodPublisher, BeBook, 10003
OldPublisher, N-Book, 20009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    distinct on (pub_name),
    pub_name,
    book_name,
    selling
from (
    select
        publisher.pub_name,
        book.book_name,
        sum(rank.selling) selling
    from
        publisher
        inner join 
        book on book.id_pub = publisher.id
        inner join
        rank on rank.id_book = book.id
    group by 1, 2
) s
order by pub_name, s.selling desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a window function. See [the window functions tutorial in the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  rank() OVER (PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY sum_of_sold DESC) AS pos
-- ... FROM clause etc here ...
WHERE pos = 1;
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about rank. So something like SELECT ..., rank() OVER (PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY selling DESC) AS pos ... WHERE pos = 1. Going to remember that one.

Comment: I prefer Clodoaldo's answer because it goes straight to the point. Despite window function works for it also, even for more complex situations.